# Need help troubleshooting cryptic message in Google Charts Timeline ['undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'this.Vn[0].v')]

Tags: javascript, php, json, google-visualization

I am having trouble getting Google Charts Timeline working with JSON/PHP. Initially I got an error that said "3 or 4 columns is required" so I fixed up the data but now I am getting the following cryptic error message:

```
['undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'this.Vn[0].v')]
```

My guess is there is something wrong with my JSON. Here is the output of my PHP script which provides the data:

```
{ "cols": 
[ {"id":"a","label":"Col1","pattern":"","type":"string"},
  {"id":"b","label":"Col2","pattern":"","type":"string"},
  {"id":"c","label":"Start","pattern":"","type":"date"},
  {"id":"d","label":"Stop","pattern":"","type":"date"} 
],
    "rows": 
    [ 
      {"c":[{"v":"test1","f":null},
            {"v":"test2","f":null},
            {"v":"2009-04-12T20:44:55","f":null},
            {"v":"2009-04-12T20:45:55","f":null}
            ]
      }, 
     ] 
}
```

Here is part of the main page's HTML/JS in case it is relevant.

```
<html>
  <head>


<!--Load the AJAX API-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

// Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart','table','timeline']});

// Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
  var jsonData = $.ajax({
      url: "ar2_1_data.php",
      dataType:"json",
      async: false
      }).responseText;

  // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

  // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
  var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(document.getElementById('chart1_div'));
  chart.draw(data, {width: 500, height: 320, title: 'Timeline'});
}

</script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="chart1_div"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone help me figure out what this error message means?

Answer (score 0):

My problem was the dates were not in the right format. I used the following code and put the resultant string inside of "Date(...)".

```
$stopdate = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $row['STOPTIME']);
$stopfor = $stopdate->format('Y,m,d,H,i,s');
```